# Does Yammer have an embedded commenting function that can be used on a separate intranet

Tags: facebook-comments, disqus, yammer, comments

Does Yammer have something like Disqus type commenting that can be embedded? Facebook has this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) but I'm looking for a corporate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the OpenGraph commenting in Yammer to perform a similar action, for example publishing articles on the intranet and have the comments be stored in Yammer and displayed on the intranet article's page. You can use Yammer Embed to achieve this, though the functions are limited and not like Disqus (allowing moderation for example is not an option, or upvoting (other than liking a comment) and no attachments), but basic post, reply and like are there and of course it is all stored in Yammer which helps with the knowledge retention aspect. Please see the Yammer developer documentation on how to do this https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/commenting

Comment: That's for the tip. Tried it now and it's roundabout what I was looking for. I'm having layout problems though. The iframe that is being created doesn't resize when I add a comment so I get a scroll bar. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks:) Hmm, on the iFrame - are you using SharePoint or another CMS to hold the Embed? There's no native support in the Embed JS to resize dynamically, have to do that with a 'helper' page to resize the iFrame.